# Django model attribute and database field with different name in model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a database table called Person contains following columns:

```
 Id,
 first_name,
 last_name,
```

So is there any way to assign different name to table fields in django model.
like this

```
class Person(models.Model):
firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
```

firstname instead of first_name

and

lastname instead of last_name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#db-column) to the field to customise the column name for a field

```
class Person(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_column='first_name')
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_column='last_name')
```